# Filtering out assets from precaching in create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm using React 17 with cra-template-pwa to create a PWA. One of my UI libraries has several hundred static image resources that all get preloaded in the PWA (and I don't use most of them). This causes a long delay in enabling the PWA, and even causes Lighthouse to crash. I'm looking at various approaches to fixing the problem, but for a quick fix just to run lighthouse, I'd like to just disable precaching. I haven't been able to find concrete info how to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution would entail using the `exclude` option in the `workbox-webpack-plugin` configuration, but that requires [`eject`ing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) in `create-react-app`.

Something you can do without `eject`ing, though, is to explicitly filter out entries from the injected `self.__WB_MANIFEST` array before passing the value to `precacheAndRoute()`.

Your `service-worker.js` could look something like:

```
import {precacheAndRoute} from 'workbox-precaching';

// self.__WB_MANIFEST will be replaced with an
// Array<{url: string, revision: string}> during the build process.

// This will filter out all manifest entries with URLs ending in .jpg
// Adjust the criteria as needed.
const filteredManifest = self.__WB_MANIFEST.filter((entry) => {
  return !entry.url.endsWith('.jpg');
});

precacheAndRoute(filteredManifest);
```

The downsides of this approach is that your `service-worker.js` file will be a bit larger than necessary (since it will include inline `{url, revision}` entries that aren't needed), and that you'll end up triggering the service worker update flow more than strictly necessary, if the contents of one of your images changes. Those unnecessary service worker updates won't actually harm anything or change the behavior of your web app, though.

Comment: Brilliant! I should've thought of that!